# Promise error in ASP.NET Boilerplate (Core 2.0 + Angular 5) Free Template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, sweetalert, aspnetboilerplate, angular5

I have been using ASP.NET Boilerplate to do CRUD Operations with the database with a REST API client like Postman using custom APIs and so far , it's working quite well.

But then when I move on to the frontend part, there is **an unhandled exception** in Users Component after logging in with an Admin account. First of all, I can see the list of users that I added, from which I can say the `Create` and `Get` operations are running properly (I also tested editing the users and it worked well). When I get to "`Deleting`" the users, I can see *an exception in the console output* as shown in the picture:

[image: Exception in Delete User operation]

I thought I had somehow messed up some of the codes, so I **redownloaded the whole template and started freshly** to performed the delete operation again. *The error still persists.*

Moreover, when I add my own service class in the `service-proxies.tx` and export it in its `service-proxy.module.ts`, and inject the service into the `app.component` and `console.log` the response in the constructor, I still get the same exception.

Please help me dig to the root of the problem. Thank you.

### Edit 1:

Here is the code in HTML line: 50:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect waves-block" (click)="delete(user)">
       <i class="material-icons">delete_sweep</i>{{l('Delete')}}</a>
</li>
```

On, the TS side, it is calling the `delete` function with `User` DTO.
On the TS side, the `delete(User)` looks like:

```
protected delete(user: UserDto): void {
    abp.message.confirm(
        "Delete user '" + user.fullName + "'?",
        (result: boolean) => {
            if (result) {
                this._userService.delete(user.id)
                    .subscribe(() => {
                        abp.notify.info("Deleted User: " + user.fullName);
                        this.refresh();
                    });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

### Edit 2:

I upgraded the SweetAlert version from 1.1.3 to 2.0.8 and the application fails to even compile. According to some GitHub threads, I'm supposed to override some functions related to the SweetAlert module. But then the error messages say the application cannot even locate `.....node_modules\sweetalert\dist\sweetalert.css.js`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ABP v3.2.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases/tag/v3.2.0) had a few **Breaking Changes**:

> [#2145](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2145) Upgrade to sweetalert v2.x. [Existing applications should upgrade sweetalert packages to v2.x.](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2694)

The free template may not have upgraded that yet.

You can upgrade to SweetAlert v2.0.8. Remove the **node_modules** folder before using **yarn**.

## Update

You can now [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) `v3.4.1` of the template with the SweetAlert upgrade.