# Data service exception in ASP.NET Boilerplate (Core 2.0 + Angular 5) Free Template

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate, angular5, typescript2.4

I created a test API that returns a sample string in the .NET application and it has been working well using REST API clients like Postman. But when I try to retrieve the data via data service in Angular app in the boilerplate and try to `console.log` the response, I got an exception as shown below:

[image: Exception when loading the component]

Basically I added a simple class in the `service-proxy.ts` file where almost all the services are stored in the app.

```
@Injectable()

export class TestService {

    constructor(private http: Http){

    }

    testRetrieve(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:21021/api/services/app/User/GetTest');
    }
}
```

Then I added the class in the module file, `service-proxy.module.ts` and inject it in the user component to call the function in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _userService: UserServiceProxy,
    private tstSrv: TestService
) {
    super(injector);
    this.tstSrv.testRetrieve().subscribe(res => console.log);
}
```

I have no idea why it's giving me this kind of error. **I cannot write any simpler code in Angular than this.** The `testRetrieve()` function returns just a simple observable, and I just need to `subscribe()` to that. But still, something is going *wrong* in the background, and the app is looking for `then` somewhere down the line.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: The client-side error is the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649563/a-built-in-error-in-asp-net-boilerplate-core2-0-angular-5-free-template). Resolve that first.

Comment: @aaron This is just a very simple piece of code cos it never uses any external libraries and stuffs. I'm just trying to `subscribe` and `console.log` the observable's response in the constructor.

Comment: if you use Angular5 use HttpClient, not Http